# Email date lost after moving mailboxes from Gmail to Exchange using Apple Mail

Tags: gmail, email

My university has decided to move its working platform from Google to Microsoft and has asked everyone to manually move emails from Gmail to Microsoft Exchange using third-party software.

I chose to use Apple Mail since it's the default on Mac.

However, after dragging the emails in the inbox and dropping them into the Exchange account, I found that all the emails lost their receiving dates and acquired the dates got copied as the receiving dates. This issue seems to be similar to an old issue described [here](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2270537).

Does any experienced user know how to fix this bug about Apple Mail?

Comment: You asked this question a while ago, but maybe you can still try using a local folder as an intermediate step, that is, copying the messages from Gmail to a local folder first, and then from there to Exchange. To create a local folder, select Mailbox > New Mailbox..., choose "On My Mac" as location, type a name and press OK.